# Wiring to connect three USB 3A receptacles (to connect my laptop to an active usb hub from one of two locations)

Tags: usb, wiring, usb-hub

I'm a total noob in electronics ) I am trying to solder three USB 3A receptacles in a way that would allow me to connect my laptop to my active USB hub from either of two locations (there will be only 2 devices at any given time). Here's a simple wiring diagram I made. I am going to just connect similar pins on all the receptacels. Is it right?

[image]

Comment: An arrangement like that might work if you just want to share power but is unlikely to work with the data lines which require matched impedances and twisted pair cables. USB hubs have active electronics - not just parallel connection of sockets. You've also used type-A sockets everywhere and it's not clear why you have nine connections to each socket when USB needs four.

Comment: It's a USB 3.0, hence 9 connectors. I am going to use twisted pairs from a USB cable, and they'll be very short. like an inch long, placed on a small breadboard, so my guess is that impendance won't really matter.

Comment: @Artem USB 3.0 works in the frequencies of 5 GHZ, any stub longer than 0.75CM (1/8 wavelength) can already give problems. An inch is 2.54cm, which is way above the limit, so bits gets merged together. With the speeds of USB 3.0, there are a large number of bits traveling in the case at once, every 6cm contains its own bit. And don't even think about leaving cables plugged into the unused port

Comment: In addition to your "like an inch long" already creating stubs which are too long, any cable you leave plugged in adds onto the stub length.

Comment: Thank you @Ferrybig. I did not think of the plugged-in cable this way. Ferrybig, didn't you think of turning your comment into an actual anwser?

Comment: Thank you @brhans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed solution would not work, USB works at 5 GHz signal frequencies.

With these fast changing signals, electricity behaves more like waves, instead of just the typical thinking that every point has the same voltage. This is also why USB 3.0 has 1 pair dedicated for sending, and the other for receiving, it is less complex to communicate this way.

The maximum stub length at 5 GHz should be 0.75CM, which you planned 1 inch is already to much.

One other issue is that you are planning to leave the cables connected to the USB headers, this is going to further increase the distance the signals have to travel to encounter a dead end.

We can put the planned circuit in a simulator, to see how it really affects the signal, [it does not look good](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCDMB0YEwFYCmBae5qTgFngBjjzAE4wEA2BOOEBPcW+5NMAKAHcQB2cgDiioheYcgJp4OQkWKmiE6CZ2Fz0PfvPGTlM3uWwzF3PuGI1d+kps5gyNS+DhYTV8LZnwnkQRIBOtOPz22NiBpiD0xL7+-F40wTHeIJGsAObRIPHp2Hrh4anpAeoBUHj69BJpaiCFRjGluRVCOTXmJWV5lcaZVdntjVT85HhFgzgN+VVD-JNj5fmtmQs5c2k2gplrccsdroI1m23jfh52YSfVvPwRUeexDk6Z1-nnG45bfc9vF4FfkPVzYC4EFa9gO9noMEgqGISQiogkgOBOTuBzuEMw0NhSXhrER6Q0tVoCigsAQzBhkWxeTxAxkVTRJLwTOZLNZ2ExlOIOJpxXsVXBjNZQuZ7JQFLheQASt8oLx9DVcPDqoxhfQwNBROquA1oAhcYJIHKZJkGRB0ZB9TRDRYwhswmrcpD9QgZXdrQY8px3W6jeDWNKandEKIGaJsExqrqdXqAPZQOK5AAewiINBdeFguRo4njUHC0Dw6dYcZIGSTwhs4gLzJ4cGIkGI2AQkHg6czECrLpQIRMeYzhbyccIZfoyZs6DbHeVGa7PeHkHzA4kQA). The pulses travel down the 0.5 meter attached cable at the bottom, and bounce back, fully masking the intended signal. You have to realise, that with 5GHz, every 5cm houses a signal transition. At 22nanoseconds into the simulation, it is too hard to decode the signal in the lower right scope.

---

You need to go for alternative approaches. Consider using a chip like the [HD3SS6126](https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/HD3SS6126RUAR?qs=3oHdzXquMOxuOQpaguz6Og%3D%3D), which can act as a USB 2.0 and 3.0 KVM switch. As seen in figure 6, it can switch from 2 sources into 1 destination. (note that you need more circuity if you want to support having both cables plugged in at the same time, without extra circuity, you could damage one of your hosts by backfeeding)

Answer (score 2):

That is not how USB works. You can't just split the cables and have three connectors on same wire. USB connections are point-to-point.

Comment: Thank you @Justme, I appreciate your answer. Would you also clarify please? My idea was that there would be always only two devices, but one of them (a laptop) would be connected in one place or another. Is this the setup that you said wouldn't work, or you thought I was going to make a usb hub? I saw Ferrybig's comment, I just want to understand your answer better.

Comment: @Artem No I did not think you were making an USB hub. You are making a thing with three USB connectors and that's not possible, USB does not allow such a thing to exist and it would not work. If it was as easy as to solder three connectors together, such things would already exist, and there would be no need for expensive USB switches which do exist and do what you propose.

Comment: Thank you Justme.